# openvz df show all mountpoint containers

Tags: openvz

Welcome,
After install openvz in debian whezzy, and create containers, df in node show all mountpoint :

> root@lab:~# df -h   System plików
>   rozm. użyte dost. %uż. zamont. na udev
>   10M     0   10M   0% /dev tmpfs
>   786M  412K  785M   1% /run
>   /dev/disk/by-uuid/fa994ffe-9e83-4f5a-acbc-8cb9f1c1ac65   37G  1,1G
>   34G   4% / tmpfs
>   5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock tmpfs
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /run/shm /dev/md2
>   411G  828M  389G   1% /vz /var/lib/vz/private/10
>   20G  324M   20G   2% /vz/root/10 tmpfs
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /vz/root/10/sys/fs/cgroup devtmpfs
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /vz/root/10/dev tmpfs
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /vz/root/10/dev/shm tmpfs
>   3,9G  8,1M  3,9G   1% /vz/root/10/run tmpfs
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /vz/root/10/run/lock none
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /vz/root/10/run/shm tmpfs
>   3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /vz/root/10/tmp /var/lib/vz/private/20
>   2,0G  323M  1,7G  16% /vz/root/20 devtmpfs
>   128M     0  128M   0% /vz/root/20/dev tmpfs
>   128M     0  128M   0% /vz/root/20/dev/shm tmpfs
>   128M  4,1M  124M   4% /vz/root/20/run tmpfs
>   5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /vz/root/20/run/lock tmpfs
>   128M     0  128M   0% /vz/root/20/sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs
>   128M     0  128M   0% /vz/root/20/tmp none
>   128M     0  128M   0% /vz/root/20/run/shm

How to remove/delete visibe mountpoint all containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have link from /etc/mtab to /proc/mounts. You can try removing this link, copy contents of /proc/mounts to /etc/mtab and remove all occurrences of /vz/root from the mtab. After that mount would keep correct contents of mtab without /vz/root

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  I guess you could pipe the output to grep with the -v option and filter out what you don't want to see.